# Error while using uuid library in SvelteKit app

Tags: sveltekit

I'm struggling with using uuid library in SvelteKit. When I try to generate UUID then I got this error: "Cannot find module 'uuid' imported from ..."

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

export async function POST({ request }) {
    const uuidId = uuid(); // throws "Cannot find module 'uuid' imported from ..."
    return { };
}
```

I'm using this uuid npm package: @types/uuid@9.0.1

Comment: that npm package is just providing you with types for typescript, don't forget to also have the uuid package itself

Comment: Oh, you are right. I misunderstood what's the function of a "@types" package. I thought that a "@types" package will install TS version of a package. Anyways installing the "uuid" npm package fix the issue. Thanks.